# Community Promotion Ads - 2018

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's almost February in 2018, which isn't supposed to be the proper time to cycle these, but for this year it'll be once again, so we'll be refreshing the **Community Promotion Ads** for this year now!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- at-the-office story blogs
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/5032).

Comment: Clarifying question: Are these for ads that will be seen on workplace.SE? Or elsewhere in the network?

Comment: @BradC indeed, this: "Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar." is not clear to me what main site means (TWP main? SE main?)

Comment: @DarkCygnus "Main site" when mentioned on meta will always refer to the parent site of the meta site you're on, in this case [workplace.se]. "Main meta" will refer to [meta.se]. There is no real main SE site as such. the root for SE will simply show the HNQ.

Comment: Another question, when is the deadline to submit possible ads? Or will they be continuously being integrated to the ads that meet the threshold as they go over it?

Comment: @DarkCygnus no deadline; any time an ad posted here reaches a score of 6, it's added to the pool.  If it falls below 6, it's removed.  There's probably some caching involved, but other than that, if there's some conference in October that you want to start advertising in July, that's fine (if the community concurs).

Comment: Thanks @MonicaCellio for clarifying. Great feature that way don't you think? So ads can be added dynamically as they (and when they) reach the thresh, enabling us to keep add content freshened up with new suggestions

Comment: @DarkCygnus agreed.  Content can be refreshed, things that come up during the year (like new site proposals) can be included, and things can be removed if no longer relevant.  I've seen some sites advertise industry conferences, which have implicit expiration dates, for example.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Support a SE for Sales and Marketing]
<sub>(source: [stackexchange.com](https://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/110851.png))</sub>

Comment: Startups SE received 13 upvotes and 4 clicks a day from a similar community promotion ad. As they didn't survive Beta; me and some of the others from that very proposal have started over with better definition. See for reference: https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3023

Answer (score 0):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Comment: Is there a way to know the current ads that TWP has?

Comment: @DarkCygnus There is a way, though I don't believe TWP currently has any. You can see what [Academia](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3661) has, for example. If you look at [last year's post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4284/community-promotion-ads-2017), none of the suggested ads made it past the 6-vote requirement.

Comment: @DarkCygnus I just noticed the link to our current ad set, the last line of the main post above: "[here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/5032)". It appears that we do not currently have any ads.

Comment: @DavidK Indeed, none of the current suggestions meet the +6 threshold. The last time we had ads [was in 2015](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3023).